# How can I blur an image in Julia?

Tags: image, julia, blur

I have an image I've loaded as an array of pixels (with Image.jl). How can I blur that image using a simple function that just averages the pixels with some number of the surrounding pixels?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple `blurred(img, n)` function that blurs every pixel in an image with the surrounding `n` pixels.

The only tricky bit here is deciding what to do at the edges. In this case, I've mirrored the edges (via `getpixel`), which I think gives a decent blur.

This algorithm is very naive, though, so it performs badly when n gets much larger than around 50...

```
# --------------------------
# using Images, FileIO
#
# include("blur.jl")
#
# img = FileIO.load("img.png")
#
# FileIO.save("blurred.png", blurred(img, 20))
# --------------------------

using Statistics: mean

function blurred(image, n)
    reshape([
        blurred_px(image, x,y, n)
        for x in 1:size(image)[1], y in 1:size(image)[2]
    ], size(image))
end

function blurred_px(image, x,y, n)
    mean(
        getpixel(image, i, j)
        for i in x-n:x+n, j in y-n:y+n
    )
end

function getpixel(image, x,y)
    w,h = size(image)
    # mirror over top/left
    x,y = abs(x-1)+1, abs(y-1)+1
    # mirror over the bottom/right
    if x > w
        x = w+ (w - x)
    end
    if y > h
        y = h+(h - y)
    end
    return image[x, y]
end

blurred
```

For example:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this answer a part of the question? Are you looking for a more performant way to blur an image than the example you show here?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm contributing it as _an_ answer, since I couldn't find an answer to this question elsewhere, but i'm hoping someone else will come by and contribute a _better_ answer. :)